# How can I size the 'space markup' conveyor?

Tags: anylogic

I apologise in advance for this very simple question, but I really don't seem to be able to find the answer to this.

I am simulating a known conveyor system. I know the length of the conveyor between station A and station B. How can I get my 'space markup' conveyor to represent my known conveyor length? e.g. 10 metres

I thought maybe it was something related to the 'convey' element linked to the conveyor, but I can't see anything there. Also, the size panel in the conveyor properties only shows the conveyor length in relation to the x and y axis on the screen, not in relation to metres. Seems strange when the conveyor speed works in metres per second!

TIA for any help!

[My Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK7xl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Space markup distances in AnyLogic are generally defined by the length drawn in the editor in pixels in combination with the scale that each Agent (including the Main agent) has.

[image: Screenshot Scale Conveyor]

In the screenshot the scale is set to 1 meters = 10 pixels and in the properties of the conveyor element you can check that the line drawn has 100 pixels hoizontal length, eg. the simulation will now take 10 meters for any duration calculation of movement etc.

Comment: That'a exactly what I was looking for - I knew it had to be right in front of me! Thank you very much!